# Silverlight Component No Longer Exists

Tags: silverlight, devexpress

I'm updating an old Silverlight 3 application to Silverlight 4. However, the version of DevExpress I'm updating to doesn't have some of the controls that were in the old version, namely the AgMenu and AgCore components. I've been Googling and I found that the Ag components were subsumed into another group of components at some point.

I'm currently trying to use DevExpress 12.1. What DevExpress components are most similar to  the Ag components?

Answer (score 2):

The last release that includes the AgDataGrid and AgMenu components is 10.2.11. These controls are Silverlight 4 compatible. The first build that supports the latest version of Silverlight(5) is 11.2. Therefore, mentioned components are not compatible with the latest version of Silverlight.

The latest versions of DXperience(12.1) include DXGrid and DXBars components that have similar functionality and extend the features set of the AgDataGrid and AgMenu controls. You can see these new controls in action in [DevExpress Silverlight Demo Center](http://demos.devexpress.com/DemoCenter/Silverlight/).

Comment: I just installed DevExpress 10.2.11, but my project contains a reference to `DevExpress.Agcore`, which I can't find in v10.2.11.